# Raspberry PI 4 camera snapshot not working

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project with raspberry pi 4 and a camera. I wanted to try and check if the camera was up and running but I am running into an issue when attempting to take a snapshot. I have set up the camera correctly as the camera is detected by the raspberry pi.
Below are some of the commands I run:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera

supported=1 detected=1
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -v

"raspistill" Camera App (commit bab9bf8790cd Tainted)

Camera Name imx219

Width 3280, Height 2464, filename (null)

Using camera 0, sensor mode 0

GPS output Disabled

Quality 85, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Time delay 5000, Timelapse 0
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC

mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled

mmal: main: Failed to create camera component

mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

The above is the error I am getting, I assume the problem is that the camera is being used by another processes, but I do not know how to find those process.

Any input on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is picamera enabled?

Comment: wrong site to ask this, also not related to the `opencv` tag. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/what-causes-enospc-error-when-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module

Comment: Are you running bullseye or some other release? Why do you think some other device is using the camera? Did you try upgrading the firmware as suggested? `sudo rpi-eeprom-update`